# Qpython or Qpython3?

Tags: android, galaxy-tab, qpython, qpython3

I'd like to try Qpython on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 running Android 4.4.2. Which would be better, in terms of stability, functionality, supported libraries, etc., Qpython or Qpython3? Or can they be installed side-by-side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can install and run both the apps.It is better to install both because qpython uses python2.7 where as qpython3 uses python3.x.The syntax are different for both the versions so obviously the libraries.
    There is a pip console in qpython to install libraries where as in qpython3 it is not there.

Comment: In Qpython3 you can use pip like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598880/how-do-i-install-modules-on-qpython3-android-port-of-python