# How do I install modules on qpython3 (Android port of python)

Tags: python, module, qpython, qpython3

I found this great module on within and downloaded it as a zip file. Once I extracted the zip file, i put the two modules inside the file(setup and the main one) on the module folder including an extra read me file I needed to run. I tried installing the setup file but I couldn't install it because the console couldn't find it. So I did some research and I tried using pip to install it as well, but that didn't work. So I was wondering if any of you could give me the steps to install it manually and with pip (keep in mind that the setup.py file needs to be installed in order for the main module to work).

Thanks!

Comment: Qpython has recently (a day ago) gone open source. Submit an issue and someone might help https://github.com/qpython-android

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The cleanest and simplest way I have found is to use pip from within QPython console as in [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code)

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'networkx'])
```

Answer (score 3):

**Step1:** Install [QPython](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.qpython.qpy).

**Step2:** Install [AIPY](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.aipy.app) for QPython.

**Step3:** Then go to QPython-->QPYPI-->AIPY and install from there Numpy, SciPy, Matplotlib, openCV etc.

Comment: Link to AIPY is broken.  I don't find anything by that name on Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the zip file to the site-packages folder.
Find the qpyplus folder in that Lib/python3.2/site-packages extract here that's it.Now you can directly use your module from REPL terminal by importing it.

Comment: This will not work for things that have external dependencies as most pip packages do.