# How can I install OpenCV on QPython?

Tags: opencv, qpython, qpython3

I ran "pip install opencv" in the QPython pip console and got the following error:

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement opencv            
No distributions at all for opencv
```

Is there a way that I can manually install opencv into my phone?

Comment: you can see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598880/how-do-i-install-modules-on-qpython3-android-port-of-python/49348725#49348725

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below - 
install opencv-qpython