# does python modules like pyaudio works in a android if an android app is make by using python?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I need a solution for this (I haven't tried it in mobile yet cause the program is in the development stage but I know the question will also get a late response) that if I have multiple modules installed via command prompt and if I use those modules to make an android app then will the app function as it did in the PC or will it say that the modules are missing and keep on crashing, I'm new to app development please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important thing to know is that PyAudio provides Python bindings for PortAudio, a cross-platform audio I/O library.
It unifies APIs from every OS like ASIO for professional Audio WASAPI for Windows, Core Audio for Mac and ALSA for Linux, etc. so you want to know if PortAudio support Android.

Have a look here:
https://source.android.com/devices/audio

Android is using ALSA, which PortAudio supports, so Pyaudio should support it as well. I guess the only way to make sure is to try it out. :)

Comment: I'm still working on the prototype and haven't implemented everything yet can you suggest Android app development framework which uses Python and can also use all of the python modules (thanks for the above reply)

Comment: I just googled (have heard about it, but not used it myself): https://www.qpython.com/
There is also a Stackoverflow question about installing modules there via pip :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598880/how-do-i-install-modules-on-qpython3-android-port-of-python/39722699

Comment: it's actually an python environment for android and it's project will only work on others mobile if they have downloaded it not what i was looking for .TBH i have been searching alot and haven't found solutions might drop my project plan.

Comment: Ok, what about: https://docs.beeware.org/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial-5/android.html
BeeWare, so you can build an .apk for android end users?

From this Stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49955489/how-to-make-android-app-completely-in-python

Answer (score 0):

If you include the module in the compilation process (I don't know what you're using for compiling/developing so not sure how to help there) the app won't crash. In the worst case it will just not play the audio, but the rest of the app should work (*unless some part of it **requires** the audio to be played*).

Comment: I'm still working on the prototype and haven't implemented everything yet can you suggest Android app development framework which uses Python and can also use all of the python modules

Comment: I would recommend you Kivy and Beeware. Those are the only two I know, but there are probably more out there